# Vb.Net MS Publisher Strings Array To TextBox Problem 

Tags: vb.net, vba, textbox, ms-office, publisher

I am creating a Simple Publisher Application in which I need to insert texts in different textbox from an array of strings .I have coded it like this .

```
    Dim texts(40) As String 'Array of strings to be inserted 

    shpTextBox = appPub.ActiveDocument.Pages(pageIndex).Shapes.AddTextbox _
          (Orientation:=PbTextOrientation.pbTextOrientationHorizontal, _
          Left:=pbShape.Left - 20, Top:=pbShape.Top, _
          Width:=72, Height:=18)


                'add text 
                shpTextBox.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = texts(Index)'Problem here , Only First array value is populating to very first text box , rest are empty strings.

                Index = Index + 1
```

Now It only populates first text box with the first string in the array (For 0th index) and rest textboxes contains empty strings ,though texts array has values.

Any help would be highly appreciated .

Thanks.

Comment: You have texts(40) at the top, but what you're putting in shpTextBox is typeText. Clarify?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out , Its texts(Index)..!!

Comment: Have edited it .Thanks . Now looking  for the solution..!!

Comment: is there just one shpTextBox, or are you making that inside the loop also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the code to C# and its working fine now...!!